# Generate a Kirkman triple system

Tags: code-golf, math, number-theory, combinatorics, combinatorial-design

Given a universe of \$v\$ elements, a **Kirkman triple system** is a set of \$(v-1)/2\$ *classes* each having \$v/3\$ *blocks* each having three elements, so that

- every pair of elements appears in exactly one block
- all classes are partitions of the universe.

[Kirkman's schoolgirl problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirkman%27s_schoolgirl_problem) corresponds to the \$v=15\$ case.

> Fifteen young ladies in a school walk out three abreast for seven days in succession: it is required to arrange them daily so that no two shall walk twice abreast.

---

Below is a procedure to construct a Kirkman triple system for \$v=3q\$ where \$q\$ is a prime number* of the form \$6t+1\$, from my MSE answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4510645/357390):

> Label elements as \$(x,j)\$ where \$x\in\mathbb F_q\$ and \$j\in\{0,1,2\}\$. Let \$g\$ be a primitive element of \$\mathbb F_q\$. Define blocks
> $$Z=\{(0,0),(0,1),(0,2)\}\\
> B_{i,j}=\{(g^i,j),(g^{i+2t},j),(g^{i+4t},j)\},0\le i<t,0\le j<2\\
> A_i=\{(g^i,0),(g^{i+2t},1),(g^{i+4t},2)\},0\le i<6t$$
> and the class
> $$C=\{Z\}\cup\{B_{i,j}:0\le i<t,0\le j<2\}\cup\{A_i:0\le i<6t,\lfloor i/t\rfloor\in\{1,3,5\}\}$$
> Define shifting a block \$b\$ by \$s\in\mathbb F_q\$ as
> $$b+s=\{(x+s,j):(x,j)\in b\}$$
> and shifting a class similarly, then a Kirkman triple system of order \$3q\$ is
> $$\{C+s:s\in\mathbb F_q\}\cup\{\{A_i+s:s\in\mathbb F_q\}:0\le i<6t,\lfloor i/t\rfloor\in\{0,2,4\}\}$$

### Task

Given a prime number \$q\$ of the form \$6t+1\$, output all classes and blocks of a Kirkman triple system on \$v=3q\$ elements. You may use any distinct values for the elements. Formatting is flexible, but the boundaries between elements, blocks and classes must be clear.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf); fewest bytes wins. You must be able to run your code to completion for at least the smallest case \$q=7\$.

### Test cases

This is a possible output for \$q=7\$:

```
[[[0, 7, 14],[1, 2, 4],[8, 9, 11],[15, 16, 18],[3, 13, 19],[6, 12, 17],[5, 10, 20]],
 [[1, 8, 15],[2, 3, 5],[9, 10, 12],[16, 17, 19],[4, 7, 20],[0, 13, 18],[6, 11, 14]],
 [[2, 9, 16],[3, 4, 6],[10, 11, 13],[17, 18, 20],[5, 8, 14],[1, 7, 19],[0, 12, 15]],
 [[3, 10, 17],[0, 4, 5],[7, 11, 12],[14, 18, 19],[6, 9, 15],[2, 8, 20],[1, 13, 16]],
 [[4, 11, 18],[1, 5, 6],[8, 12, 13],[15, 19, 20],[0, 10, 16],[3, 9, 14],[2, 7, 17]],
 [[5, 12, 19],[0, 2, 6],[7, 9, 13],[14, 16, 20],[1, 11, 17],[4, 10, 15],[3, 8, 18]],
 [[6, 13, 20],[0, 1, 3],[7, 8, 10],[14, 15, 17],[2, 12, 18],[5, 11, 16],[4, 9, 19]],
 [[1, 9, 18],[2, 10, 19],[3, 11, 20],[4, 12, 14],[5, 13, 15],[6, 7, 16],[0, 8, 17]],
 [[2, 11, 15],[3, 12, 16],[4, 13, 17],[5, 7, 18],[6, 8, 19],[0, 9, 20],[1, 10, 14]],
 [[4, 8, 16],[5, 9, 17],[6, 10, 18],[0, 11, 19],[1, 12, 20],[2, 13, 14],[3, 7, 15]]]
```

---

<sub>*The construction also works for \$q\$ any prime **power** of the form \$6t+1\$, but I know some languages may be disadvantaged in implementing general finite field arithmetic. Cf. [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/75786/110698).</sub>

Answer (score 1):

## [Python](https://www.python.org) with numpy, 285 bytes

```
from numpy import*
def k(q):
    t=q//6;a=array;r=range;R=a(r(q-1));X=R//t%2;h=a(r(3));g=1;p=lambda x:[(x+s)%q for s in r(q)]
    while 1in g**R[1:]%q:g+=1
    A=a([g**(i+2*h*t)%q+h/5for i in R]);return[p(i)for i in A[X<1]]+p(a([h/5]+[(g**(i+2*h*t))%q+j/5for i in r(t)for j in h]+list(A[X>0])))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TZFLbsIwFEXVYbKHSp4g7BiUhqofxXUltpBOkCIPTMnHJHGch1FhLZ0waffUrgYb-uHNfO67Z_D8_mn2tu714fCxteX08fvquoS-Q3rbmT1SnenBRuGqKFGDB5KGgeVDHN8zySWA3DPgIHVVsIxLDHiYJoSwBc_i2I5mrD7BW4cqnjDDW9ktVxLt0hzv6IaMBlT2gDZIaeS6RITBW63aAiUOVFGU5UkqRkNaUZ6EwdzJckexorOojqyr0zq-8wblDZkgDAq7BZ0brMgfn-eLp0QIarDru4KgOb7UeM_6wgPYnspr_6gFbdXGYid5vhGEkPOVvl78hpFg_VKDH9xlkBtPl23_2njs4zP2Y0Bpi0_hBBV6xccTNCbhf_Sj_v2IIw)

Answer (score 0):

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 218 bytes

```
q->c=concat;c([c([[[[s+0*g=znprimroot(q),j]|j<-r=[0..2]]],c([[[[g^(i+2*t*k)+s,j]|k<-r]|i<-[1..t=q\6]]|j<-r]),[[[g^(i+2*t*j)+s,j]|j<-r]|i<-u=[1..6*t],i\t%2]])|s<-v=[1..q]],[[[[g^(i+2*t*j)+s,j]|j<-r]|s<-v]|i<-u,i\t%2<1])
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=dY9NCsIwEIWv4kZI0qa0XVTBxIuko7SBlrTY39SF9CZuCiLuvY2extQouHEYGJj53jze-dYkndrnzXTJFvw66IyuH8-WbiWXdSUTvZFImDbVOz7J-alqOnXo6lqjFrsFjAWjHRe-54UA4Fo03yHlhESTEjv9DJUGglExKgLP07yNI7BKwO4vX3z44ssPfFZERIOrYr00HnjsGT2-160xFP_lM2efWC0LANuEd2FCVBqleEwZzdAKgz1Mk50v)